# Problems with compiling Android Oreo for tablet

Tags: android, linux, android-source, rom, custom-rom

Hi could someone tell me what this error is related to? I don't know whats causing it.

> Error - cannot assign to readonly variable: SOONG_CLANG_CONFIG_arm_TARGET_TRIPLE

The build log:

```
============================================
[44/44] bootstrap /home/rh/lineage/out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
[4/4] /home/rh/lineage/out/soong/.boot...neage/out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
[871/872] glob vendor/qcom/opensource/...erfaces/wifi/supplicant/1.0/Android.bp
[56/56] /home/rh/lineage/out/soong/.bo.../home/rh/lineage/out/soong/build.ninja
/home/rh/lineage/out/build-lineage_YT3850M.ninja is missing, regenerating...
/home/rh/lineage/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_YT3850M.mk:511: error: cannot assign to readonly variable: SOONG_CLANG_CONFIG_arm_TARGET_TRIPLE
14:09:27 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (55 seconds) ####

rh@inspiron:~/lineage$
```

Comment: What is your repo init and lunch command ?

Comment: Nvm I fixed it by removing all TARGET_2ND_ARCH flags

Comment: If you found a solution, you can add an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, I fixed it by removing all TARGET_2ND_ARCH variables from my BoardConfig.mk